# How to get values from different cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view that includes multiple prototype cells. I want to get values of textField in these cells and append an array, when tapped a button.

Cells has an object that called element. I want to append this element to elementsArray in my view controller. The problem is when cellForRow method worked this elements keys is created but because of cellForRowAt method works only one time, "value" key of element object take initial value of txtContent.

How can I take txtContent text after write a text for each cell?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let object = surveyDetailArray.first!.elements[indexPath.row]

switch object.type {
case CellConfig.email.rawValue:

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EmailCell", for: indexPath) as! EmailCell
        cell.lblTitle.text = object.title
        cell.txtContent.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

        cell.element["formElementId"] = object.id as AnyObject
        cell.element["options"] = optionArray as AnyObject

        elementsArray.append(cell.element as AnyObject)

        return cell

    case CellConfig.number.rawValue:

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NumberCell", for: indexPath) as!  NumberCell
        cell.lblTitle.text = object.title
        cell.txtContent.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        cell.txtContent.keyboardType = .numberPad


        cell.element["formElementId"] = object.id as AnyObject
        cell.element["options"] = optionArray as AnyObject

        elementsArray.append(cell.element as AnyObject)

        return cell
 }
```

My cell class

```
 class EmailCell: UITableViewCell,UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var txtContent: CustomTextField!

var element = ["formElementId":"",
"value":"",
"options":[]] as [String : Any]

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    txtContent.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1570051014, green: 0.1588717997, blue: 0.2081049681, alpha: 0.1)
    txtContent.layer.borderWidth = 0
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    txtContent.delegate = self
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    element["value"] = textField.text!
}

}
```

Comment: I only skimmed your question but your tableview is supposed to reflect your model data, so you should have everything you need nice and accessible.  That's how MVC works.

Answer (score 0):

```
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let object = surveyDetailArray.first!.elements[indexPath.row]

        switch object.type {
        case CellConfig.email.rawValue:

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EmailCell", for: indexPath) as! EmailCell
                cell.txtContent.delegate = self

                return cell

        case CellConfig.number.rawValue:

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NumberCell", for: indexPath) as!  NumberCell
return cell
         }


        extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{
        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        var cell: UITableView Cell!
           if let emailCell: UITableViewCell = textField.superview.superview as? EmailCell{
        cell = emailCell
        }

           if let numbCell: UITableViewCell = textField.superview.superview as? NumberCell{
        cell = numbCell
        }

            var table: UITableView = cell.superview as UITableView
            let textFieldIndexPath = table.indexPathForCell(cell)

    // HERE DO THE UPDATION YOU WANT TO DO
        }
        }
```